# Javascript Amend/convert code that reads array to work with object data

Tags: javascript

I have some code which will export some day into a csv file with reads this data format:

```
var data = [
   ['one', 'one is the first'],
   ['two', 'two is the second'],
   ['three', 'this is the third']
];
```

and here is the function that does the job:

```
function download_csv() {
    var csv = 'Name,Title\n';
    data.forEach(function(row) {
            csv += row.join(',');
            csv += "\n";
    });

    console.log(csv);
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'data.csv';
    document.getElementById('export_btn_container').appendChild(hiddenElement);
    hiddenElement.click();
}
```

and the html part:

```
<button onclick="download_csv()">Download CSV</button>
<div id="export_btn_container" style="display:none;"></div>
```

The code above works well but the data I have the start with looks like this:

```
"users":[
    {
        "id":"34",
        "name":"namehere",
        "user":{
            "id":"56",
            "username":"usernamehere",
            "firstName":"firstnamehere",
            "lastName":"lastnamehere"
        },
        "active":"yes"
    }
]}
```

My question is...how can I use the code above with the data just above?

Comment: Why one user has 2 ids ?

Comment: It's just the data that I have to work with...it's not my choice :)

Comment: Which ID do you need, there are 2 differents ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate the `users` property which is an array. For each user you get the properties you need one by one

```js
var data = {
  "users": [{
    "id": "34",
    "name": "namehere",
    "user": {
      "id": "56",
      "username": "usernamehere",
      "firstName": "firstnamehere",
      "lastName": "lastnamehere"
    },
    "active": "yes"
  }]
}

function download_csv() {
  var csv = 'Id,Name,Username,Firstname,Lastname,Active\n';
  data.users.forEach(function(user) {
    csv += user.id + ",";
    csv += user.name + ",";
    csv += user.user.username + ",";
    csv += user.user.firstName + ",";
    csv += user.user.lastName + ",";
    csv += user.active;
    csv += "\n";
  });

  console.log(csv);
  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
  hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = 'data.csv';
  document.getElementById('export_btn_container').appendChild(hiddenElement);
  hiddenElement.click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="download_csv()">Download CSV</button>
<div id="export_btn_container" style="display:none;"></div>
```

If you dont know the names of the keys you can use this code

```js
var data = {
  "users": [{
    "id": "34",
    "name": "namehere",
    "user": {
      "id": "56",
      "username": "usernamehere",
      "firstName": "firstnamehere",
      "lastName": "lastnamehere"
    },
    "active": "yes"
  }]
}

function download_csv() {
  var csv = 'Id,Name,ID,Username,Firstname,Lastname,Active\n';
  data.users.forEach(function(user) {
    //iterate all keys
    Object.keys(user).forEach(function(key){
      //is object
      if(typeof user[key] === 'object'){
        //iterate keys of nested object
        Object.keys(user[key]).forEach(function(secondKey){
          csv += user[key][secondKey] + ",";
        })
      }else{
       csv += user[key] + ","; 
      }  
    })
    //remove last comma
    csv = csv.slice(0, -1);
    csv += "\n";
  });
  console.log(csv);
  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
  hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = 'data.csv';
  document.getElementById('export_btn_container').appendChild(hiddenElement);
  hiddenElement.click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="download_csv()">Download CSV</button>
<div id="export_btn_container" style="display:none;"></div>
```